# Storage Spaces - removal of disk in Simple array

Tags: windows-10, software-raid, storage-spaces

I have a simple array set up in Storage Spaces that consists of 5 hard drives: four are 3TB and one is 2TB. I want to replace that 2TB with a larger drive, but it has 40.1 % of the disk being used (according to the Storage Spaces manager). I clicked "Remove" in the Storage Spaces Management screen, but the drive says "Preparing for removal". I tried optimizing the Storage Spaces to see if it would move the data to other drives, but it has not.  Keep in mind I have 12.7TB total with only 6.54TB being used. I have plenty of space for this drive's data to be reallocated to other drives.

Is this possible? Or does having a Simple Array just pretty much make it impossible to replace disks?

Answer (score 2):

Just needed to wait. Storage Spaces "Remove" drive actually moves the remaining data on the drive to other drives and allows you to eject the drive selected. The only issue was I am impatient and you need to wait a few hours to let that process happen.

Answer (score 1):

Running "Get-StorageJob" in PowerShell will give you the completion percentage of the removal job. It seems like for large drives this process can potentially take a very long time (>1 day).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I just had to do this, if you watch the % used of each hard drive it will slowly change. The drive you are removing will go down and the other drives will increase as the removal progresses. It is a very slow process though.